# $\kappa(B^{-1}A)=\kappa (AB^{-1}) = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(B^{-1}A)}{\lambda_{\min}(B^{-1}A)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

> Prove or disprove: if $A,B$ are symmetric positive definite (s.p.d.) matrices then operator 2-norm condition number $\kappa(B^{-1}A)=\kappa (AB^{-1}) = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(B^{-1}A)}{\lambda_{\min}(B^{-1}A)}$. Does it hold if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is s.p.d.?

There is a proof in my lecture note but they used the wrong fact that $B(B^{-1}A)B^{-1} = AB^{-1}$ is an equivalence transformation of $B^{-1}A$ hence $\kappa(B^{-1}A)=\kappa (AB^{-1})$. I have no idea about the correctness of the statement and I am unable to prove it or give a counter example. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A good first step is to perform some experiments with small matrices! Here tools such as MATLAB can be valuable when *disproving* identities. You will find that the statement under investigation is false in general, but it is certainly true if the matrices $B^{-1}A$ and $A^{-1}B$ are symmetric! There is condition which occurs frequently in pure mathematics, but less frequently in practical applications, which will ensure that this is the case. Can you find this extra condition?

Comment: Hi Carl, there is nothing to sing if $B^{-1}A$ and $A^{-1}B$ commutes. I don't want to use this. Can you prove or disprove the statement?

Comment: You just need a counter-example. Just make sure that A and B do not commute, so that $B^{-1}A$ and $A^{-1}B$ are not automatically symmetric matrices.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work !!!

Comment: Then you where extraordinarily unlucky or you did not generate a random matrix. Try $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: No, but your example has $\kappa(B^{-1}A) = \kappa(AB^{-1})$

Comment: You had one statement which contained two equalities. You did not specifiy that we had to violate both of them. My example violates the second, but not the first, because it has $B^{-1}A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&  \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 & \frac{5}{8} \end{bmatrix}$ and $\kappa(B^{-1}A) \approx 1.7553$.

Comment: My poor explanation. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Hi @Carl Do you have counter example for $\kappa(B^{-1}A) \neq \kappa(AB^{-1})$ for A,B are s.p.d. I tried many examples but it seems to be true.

Comment: Here you should find equality! Exploit that $\kappa(C)$ is determine from the spectrum of the symmetric matrix $CC^T$ or equivalently from $C^TC$. Try $C=B^{-1}A$ and $D=AB^{-1}$ and write out the (at most) 4 combinations which can be relevant.

Comment: Chiristian Thx you so much